# How do I add specific highlighting animation when button/link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

When a button/link is clicked I would like to highlight it by fading/stretching in (and then out) a new background colour.

As an example: If you go to Chrome History and click on the links 'Chrome History', 'Tabs from other devices' or 'Clear Browsing Data' it shows this effect.

How would I do that?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually google uses paper-ripple for provides a visual effect that other paper elements can use to simulate a rippling effect emanating from the point of contact. The effect can be visualized as a concentric circle with motion.

paper-ripple listens to "mousedown" and "mouseup" events so it would display ripple effect when touches on it. You can also defeat the default behavior and manually route the down and up actions to the ripple element. Note that it is important if you call downAction() you will have to make sure to call upAction() so that paper-ripple would end the animation loop.

Note, it's important that the parent container of the ripple be relative position, otherwise the ripple will emanate outside of the desired container.

[REFERENCE](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-ripple)

```js
 //jQuery time
    var parent, ink, d, x, y;
    $("ul li a").click(function(e){
     parent = $(this).parent();
     //create .ink element if it doesn't exist
     if(parent.find(".ink").length == 0)
      parent.prepend("<span class='ink'></span>");
      
     ink = parent.find(".ink");
     //incase of quick double clicks stop the previous animation
     ink.removeClass("animate");
     
     //set size of .ink
     if(!ink.height() && !ink.width())
     {
      //use parent's width or height whichever is larger for the diameter to make a circle which can cover the entire element.
      d = Math.max(parent.outerWidth(), parent.outerHeight());
      ink.css({height: d, width: d});
     }
     
     //get click coordinates
     //logic = click coordinates relative to page - parent's position relative to page - half of self height/width to make it controllable from the center;
     x = e.pageX - parent.offset().left - ink.width()/2;
     y = e.pageY - parent.offset().top - ink.height()/2;
     
     //set the position and add class .animate
     ink.css({top: y+'px', left: x+'px'}).addClass("animate");
    })
```

```css
/*custom fonts - Bitter, Montserrat*/
    @import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Bitter');
    /*basic reset*/
    * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    body {
     background-color:black;
     background-size: cover;
    }
    
    h1 {
     font: normal 32px/32px Bitter; color: white;
     text-align: center; padding: 85px 100px;
    }
    
    /*nav styles*/
    ul {
     background: white; border-top: 6px solid hsl(180, 40%, 60%);
     width: 200px; margin: 0 auto;
    }
    ul li {
     list-style-type: none;
     /*relative positioning for list items along with overflow hidden to contain the overflowing ripple*/
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    ul li a {
     font: normal 14px/28px Montserrat; color: hsl(180, 40%, 40%);
     display: block; padding: 10px 15px;
     text-decoration: none;
     cursor: pointer; /*since the links are dummy without href values*/
     /*prevent text selection*/
     user-select: none;
     /*static positioned elements appear behind absolutely positioned siblings(.ink in this case) hence we will make the links relatively positioned to bring them above .ink*/
     position: relative;
    }
    
    /*.ink styles - the elements which will create the ripple effect. The size and position of these elements will be set by the JS code. Initially these elements will be scaled down to 0% and later animated to large fading circles on user click.*/
    .ink {
     display: block; position: absolute;
     background: hsl(180, 40%, 80%);
     border-radius: 100%;
     transform: scale(0);
    }
    /*animation effect*/
    .ink.animate {animation: ripple 0.65s linear;}
    @keyframes ripple {
     /*scale the element to 250% to safely cover the entire link and fade it out*/
     100% {opacity: 0; transform: scale(2.5);}
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Ripple Click Effect</h1>
    <ul>
     <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
     <li><a>My Account</a></li>
     <li><a>Direct Messages</a></li>
     <li><a>Chat Rooms</a></li>
     <li><a>Settings</a></li>
     <li><a>Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
```

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/C3szT/114/)